# How to append (modify/edit/update) to requestHeaders using declarativeNetRequest

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to edit the request header using declarativeNetRequest:

```
{
   "id": 1, 
   "priority": 1, 
   "action": {
      "type": "modifyHeaders", 
      "requestHeaders": [{"header": "someHeader", "operation": "append", "value": "newValue"}]
   }, 
   "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "*",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame", "xmlhttprequest"]
   }
}
```

Expected Result:

The header should be modified

```
{
   name: "someHeader"
   value: "oldValue; newValue"
}
```

Actual Result:

dynamic rules:

`Unchecked runtime.lastError: Rule with id 1 must not specify a request header to be appended.`

general rules:

```
Failed to load extension
File D:\extensions\test-extensions\web\app\chrome
Error rules.json: Rule with id 1 must not specify a request header to be appended.
Could not load manifest.
```

Comment: Apparently this is a bug in Chrome. Use `set` instead of `append`.

Comment: @wOxxOm If I'm not mistaken, `set` overwrites the header, but I also need to keep the old value.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Judging by the source code this is [intentionally impossible](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/api/declarative_net_request/indexed_rule.cc;l=495-497;drc=15a616c8043551a7cb22c4f73a88e83afb94631c) for outgoing headers. I don't understand why though and what we should do in such cases because the API seems quite useless.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you=) have a nice day